# Missing data with Export CSV for multiple spiders / Scrapy / Pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I implemented a pipeline based on some example around here. I'm trying to export all informations for multiple spiders (launched by a single file and not in command line) on a single CSV file.

However, it appears that some data (around 10%) showed into the shell aren't recorded into CSV. Is this because spiders are writing at the same time?

How could I fix this into my script to collect all data in a single CSV? I'm using `CrawlerProcess` to launch the spiders.

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter


class ScrapybotPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.files = {}

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    pipeline = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    return pipeline

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    file = open('result_extract.csv', 'w+b')
    self.files[spider] = file
    self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
    self.exporter.fields_to_export = ['ean', 'price', 'desc', 'company']
    self.exporter.start_exporting()

def spider_closed(self, spider):
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
    file = self.files.pop(spider)
    file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
    return item
```

Answer (score 1):

I know from your description that you're handling multiple spiders. Just to confirm: are you handling them *at a same time*? (within *a same crawl process*)?

According to the code you shared. You're trying to maintain one output file object per spider but writing to all the same path. In `spider_opened`:

```
file = open('result_extract.csv', 'w+b')
self.files[spider] = file
```

This is believed to be the root cause of issue.

As you're having only one file (as on your filesystem) to write to, you may do it by opening it just once. Modified version of your code:

```
class ScrapybotPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = None

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.file = open('result_extract.csv', 'w+b')
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.fields_to_export = ['ean', 'price', 'desc', 'company']
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

Comment: Yes, I'm running them at the same time ! How to unify my exporter (as you mention in the last part of your comment) so that I can keep one file only for those spiders ?

Comment: @Araxide Exporter and output file are in an one-to-one relationship. To make it correct when having an unified exporter, I think you just need to rewrite the lines where you created multiple output files.

Comment: Could you precise which lines you are talking ? ^^ You mean that I should go with several output files ?