# Scrapy to csv multiple spiders

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

I'm running a news article crawler with scrapy. When I run just one spider it works but with multiple spiders it runs the crawler but fails to export to csv. I'm using the following command to run the crawler:

```
scrapy crawl <crawler name> -o file.csv -t csv
```

I have to use another export method when crawling with multiple spiders?

Comment: using Google "Scrapy to csv multiple spiders" I found [Missing data with Export CSV for multiple spiders / Scrapy / Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223801/missing-data-with-export-csv-for-multiple-spiders-scrapy-pipeline)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing data with Export CSV for multiple spiders / Scrapy / Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223801/missing-data-with-export-csv-for-multiple-spiders-scrapy-pipeline)